# Why is `select()` returning a client as writable when the client has disconnected?

Tags: python, sockets, select, network-programming

I am implementing this [example](https://pymotw.com/3/select/#using-select) for using `select` in a simple echo server. Everything works fine, the client sends the message, receives the echo and disconnects.

This is the code I used for the client:

```
import socket

ECHOER_PORT = 10000

if __name__ == '__main__':
    sockfd = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    sockfd.connect(('localhost', ECHOER_PORT))

    msg = input('Message: ').encode()

    sockfd.send(msg)
    response = sockfd.recv(len(msg))
    print('Response: {}'.format(response))
    sockfd.close()
```

The issue is with the server (full gist code is [here](https://gist.github.com/MoeEmara/b3f8b9a5cc8986b258a568a808f05bc5)), after sending the echo, `select` is called again one more time and the current client (which received the echo and disconnected) is returned from select as both readable and writable.

I understand why it's returned as readable, since according to the article:

> A readable socket without data available is from a client that has
>   disconnected, and the stream is ready to be closed.

But my question is why does return as writable also?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> But my question is why does return as writable also?

The main thing you want to have `select()` do when a client has disconnected is return immediately, so that your code can detect the disconnection-event and handle it ASAP (by closing the socket).

One way to do this is the common way, by having the server select-for-read on every socket, and when a client disconnects, `select()` will return ready-for-read on that socket, then the program will call `recv()` on the socket to find out what the data is, `recv()` will return EOF, and the server will close the socket.  That is all well and good.

Now imagine the less-common (but not unheard of) case where the server writes to its client sockets, but doesn't want to read from them.  In this case, the server has no need (or desire) to select for ready-to-read on its sockets; it only needs to select for ready-to-write, to know when there is some outgoing-data-buffer-space available to send more data to a client.  That server still needs to know when a client has disconnected, though -- which is why the disconnected socket selects as ready-for-write as well, so that a `select()` that is only watching for ready-for-write can also detect and react to a disconnected socket immediately.

Comment: But how would it detect that client has disconnected through a write operation?

Comment: By default (at least in posix-style OS’s) a SIGPIPE signal would be raised.  Or, if your program has set itself to ignore/disable SIGPIPE, then send()/write() would return -1 and set errno to EPIPE.